# How to extract pairwise diagonal in tensor in theano without for loop?

Tags: python, theano

I have a 4-dim tensor "a" with dimensions m x n x n x k.
I want to obtain the following tensor "b": using python I have:

```
 b = [a[:,0,0,3:-3]]
 for i in xrange(1,n):
    b=numpy.concatenate((b,[a[:,i,i,3:-3]]))
```

how can I convert this to theano code without using a for loop? n is around 500 so it crashes if I just do the for loop in theano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
i = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(range(n)))
b = a[:,i,i,3:-3]
```

Theano basically inherited [Numpy's array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael i've added a reference.

Comment: @user6175310 you're welcome, a lovely upvote or accept would be great :)

Comment: @dontloo I tried to give an upvote, but I am new to stackoverflow so it didn't accept my vote until I have 15 points :( :( How do I accept an answer?

Comment: @user6175310 oh i see.. there should be a tick to click under the votes, or see this FAQ for how it works in details meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… :)

Comment: @dontloo thank you! I'll definitely come back and vote after I earn 15 points :)